# Need the header font to be black when there's a white background and white when theres a dark background

Tags: css

I've tried quite a few things (I'm no coder) but can't quite seem to get it right. All of the solutions seem to be not applicable to my Squarespace theme. Your help is greatly appreciated!

This link has an example of a page where you can't see the menu items due to white background.

https://www.steffantp.com.au/projects/torres-street

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, when you scroll the page a `.shrink` class is added to the header and it change the color of the texts.

You can also change the styles that you need based on that class.

For example, you can use one of these:

```
/* To change the color of text, when page is not scrolled */
header:not(.shrink) .header-nav-item a {
    color: black !important;
}

/* To change the background of header, when page is not scrolled */
header:not(.shrink) .header-background {
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Super simple. Appreciate it.